# How do I gain system permission so that I can compile emacs' etags?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, elisp, permission-denied

How do I gain permission to run compile in emacs?

I am in the middle of creating TAGS file in a specific directory (/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp) - following through [intro to programming in Emacs Lisp by Robert Chassell](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/pdf/eintr.pdf).

I have run the compile command, 

`M-x compile RET etags *.el RET`

In return I am told that permission has been denied. This is my personal computer, running ubuntu 14.04 LTS with sudo privilege (my personal computer).

I have found some information [permission denied when running sh scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409025/permission-denied-when-running-sh-scripts) which may be applicable and is worth trying (perhaps try chmod +x *.el instead of chmod + x filename.sh in the example?) but is a little scared as these are not exact solutions and I am fairly new to programming let alone linux (I have already corrupted some files and had to install ubuntu 14.04 all over again a few days ago

The below is the actual message shown in the bufer:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/" -*-
Compilation started at Sat Jun  4 05:36:16

etags *.el
TAGS: Permission denied

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sat Jun  4 05:36:16
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can get half of tags functionality (for Emacs lisp, anyway) for free with `find-function`.  I bind it to `C-h C-f`.  There's also `find-variable`, but I find `describe-variable` (`C-h v`) to be much more useful.

---

You're probably running Emacs as a regular user rather than an administrator.  This is absolutely the correct thing to do, but will not allow you to write to system directories like anything under `/usr`.  You can either run Emacs as root (`sudo emacs`), or use a package called tramp that allows you to work as a different user (it also allows you to edit files on remote machines).

Open the directory as root with `C-x C-f /sudo:localhost:/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/`.  When you have the directory open, run `compile`.

Also, I doubt that command will do what you want.  Most Emacs installations gzip the lisp source, and while `etags` seems to be smart enough to handle this, the glob pattern `*.el` will not match.  Furthermore, there are subdirectories.  It's best to use the `find` command: `find -name "*.el" -o -name "*.el.gz" -exec etags '{}' +`.

---

**The real solution is to not put the TAGS file in that directory.**  Simply put it somewhere else where you have write permission.

```
cd; find /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp -name "*.el" -o -name "*.el.gz" -exec etags '{}' +`
```